# Как описать регулярным выражением степень скобки?

Tags: c, lex

Я хочу описать регулярным выражением на LEX ,например, вот такую ситуацию: (2x^2-3)^2*(8x^2+99). Мне бы хотелось "поймать" регулярным выражением этот весь поток символов только тогда, когда у скобки полиномов есть степень 2 или выше(задаётся через циркумфлекс(^)). Я хочу определять,есть ли у скобки степень через символы закрывающей скобки,возведения в степень и цифры , то есть `)^2`.
Как правильно составить регулярное выражение для этого?

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
[")" ^ ]*               printf("STEPEN\n")//тут буду работать с yytext; // тут непонятно, как записать регулярку
[0123456789]+           printf("NUMBER\n");
%%
```

Comment: а тебе не кажется, что такой глубокий анализ не является задачей лексера? он должен только преобразовать текстовую строку `(2x^2-3)^2` в последовательность токенов типа «`скобка1` `число` `переменная` `степень` `число` `минус` `число` `скобка2` `степень` `число`»... в крайнем случае можно объединить `степень` и `число` в один, но зачем к этому приплетать скобку?

Comment: ну а если очень хочется, то регулярка должна быть примерно такая: `\)\^([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)`, но это зачем-то будет отдельным токеном «`закрывающая_скобка_со_степенью_2_или_выше`» и сильно усложнит построение грамматики...

Comment: @Eivin Я не понимаю сути проблемы. У Вас строка ")^2" состоит исключительно из **литеральных** символов. Регулярным выражением для такой строки является сама эта строка. Ну, может быть имеет смысл разрешить пробелы вокруг '^'. Тогда RE будет выглядеть как то так: ")\b*^\b*2". Вот только не помню, нужно в RE для Lexa круглые скобки экранировать, или нет...

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое регулярное выражение

```
\((.*)\)\^2
```